# time series simulation and logical checking with Matlab or with other tools

Tags: algorithm, matlab, visual-c++, data-mining, time-series

1) I have time series data and signals (indicators) that  their value changes over time.

My question:

2) I need to do logical checking all the time, e.g. if signal 1 and 2 happened around the same time (were equal to a certain value e.g.=1) then I need to know the exact time in order to check what happened next.

3) to complicate things,e.g. if signal 3 happened in some time range after signal 1 and signal 2 were equal to 1, I would like to check other things.

4)The time series is very long and I need to deal with it segment by segment.

Please advice how to write it without inventing the wheel.
Is it recommended to write it in Matlab?, using a state machine? in C++?, using threads?

5) Does Matlab have a simulator ready for this kind of things?
How do I define the logical conditions in an efficient way?

6) Can I use data mining tools for this?
I saw this list of tools:
[Data Mining open source tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835754/data-mining-open-source-tools)
not sure where to start.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second and third question could be done like this in Matlab:

```
T = -range; % Assuming that t starts at 0.
for n = 1 : length(t)
    if signal1(n) == 1 && signal2(n) == 1
        T = t(n);
    end
    if t(n) - T < range && signal3(n) == 1
        if % Conditions you want to get checked, could also be put in the previous if statement.
            % Things you want to be executed if these coditions are met.
        end
    end
end
```

Using a lower level programming language like C++ would improve the rate at which it would be done. And if data is very long it could also reduce the amount of memory use by loading in an element of each array at the time.
Matlab has a simulator, called Simulink, but that is more meant for solving more complicated things, since you only conditionally want to do something.

Comment: Hi Fibonatic,  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Hi Fibonatic, in the beginning of your answer you wrote T=-range, and inside the loop you wrote T=t(n); without using the first T can you please explain how it works?

Comment: Hi fibonatic, I tried to run it in Matlab and I´m getting errors: range=10;
t=1:1:20;
signal1={0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
signal2={0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
signal3={0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

T = -range; % Assuming that t starts at 0.
for n = 1 : length(t)
    if ((signal1(n) == 1) && (signal2(n) == 1))
        T = t(n);
    end
    
    if t(n) - T < range && signal3(n) == 1
        
    end
    
end

Comment: T=-range initializes the value of T, such that if the first if statement hasn't been true, the second one can't be true either. If you would initialize T=0 would give the possibility that the second if statement can be true until t = range.
And I think the error is caused because you use a cell array structure for the signals. It would work if you would turn them into matrices (by replacing "{" and "}" with "[" and "]").